# Why does a standard normal with $\frac{z^2}{2}=w$ equal $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, gamma-function

In Berger, Casella (2002) I read that the standard normal pdf, given by
$$ \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\,dz$$
is equal to the gamma function $\Gamma(\alpha)$ evaluated in $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ when $w=\frac{1}{2}z^2$, which results in:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =\int^\infty_0w^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-w}dw=\sqrt{\pi}.$$

However, when I do my calculations and substitute $dz=\frac{dw}{\sqrt{2w}}$ I obtain a slightly different result, that is:
$$2^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int^\infty_0w^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-w}dw.$$

Can somebody tell me what I missed?

Comment: [Your original integral equals $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ so your computation is correct.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einfty+e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29+dx) Maybe you mis-remembered the claim from the textbook.

Comment: The whole point of the $\exp$ notation is to make superscripts unnecessary, especially when the argument to the exponential function is a highly space-consuming expression. Accordingly I edited the question so that it says $\exp\left(-\dfrac{z^2} 2 \right)$ rather than the incorrection $\exp^{-\frac {z^2}2}. \qquad $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard normal distribution is $\displaystyle \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} \, dz.$

You have $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}\, dz=1.$

Thereofore $ \displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} \sqrt{\frac 2 \pi} e^{-z^2/2} \, dz = 1.$

If $u = z^2/2$ then $z = \sqrt{2u\,\,}, $ and $du = z\,dz = \sqrt{2u\,} \,dz,$ and so $\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{2u\,}} = dz.$

So we get
$$
1 = \int_0^{+\infty} \sqrt{\frac2\pi} e^{-z^2/2}\, dz = \int_0^{+\infty} \sqrt{\frac 2\pi} e^{-u} \, \frac{du}{\sqrt{2u}} = \frac {\Gamma(1/2)}{\sqrt\pi}.
$$